# Javascript - Vue.js - Invalid handler for event "click"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I have list of elements which I want to go to edit when clicked. I got invalid handler for event "click" error when rendered but I can't find out why. I am building it with vue-cli.

Here's the code:

```
<template lang='pug'>
  div#app

    div.input-area
      ul.toggle
        li.item.i1
          button#toggle-1(v-on:click="font") Roboto
        li#item.item.i2
          button( v-on:click="font") Roboto Condensed
        li.item.i3
          button( v-on:click="font") Noto Serif
        li.item.i4
          button( v-on:click="font") Droid Sans Mono
        li.item.i5
          button( v-on:click="font") Cutive Mono
        li.item.i6
          button( v-on:click="font") Coming Soon
        li.item.i7
          button( v-on:click="font") Dancing Script
        li.item.i8
          button( v-on:click="font") Carrois Gothic SC

      textarea(width="400", height="600")
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'

var fonts = new Vue({
  el: '#toggle-1',
  data: {
    name: 'name'
  },
  methods: {
    font: function (event) {
      alert('click')
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Your outer div is `#app`, but your Vue el is `#toggle-1`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it still doesn't work. I also got undefined error for the method "font".

Comment: This [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxEjpE?editors=1011) seems to work. It did complain about the indentation of your first line.

Comment: So my environment may be wrong..?  I'll try to figure it out why, thanks for your response.

Comment: I have tried this and it says: "Vue is not defined"